# Express logic and with +,-,*

Tags: logic, boolean-algebra

How can a logic and be expressed using  only the arithmetic operators $+,-,*$ on $\{0,1\}$, taking $1 = $ True?
To be precise:
What function that uses only $+,-,*$ is $1$ when both arguments are $1$ and is $0$ otherwise for elements of $\{0,1\}$?

Comment: Do you know a truth function that has the behavior you describe? It's a very very common word in English and any other human language. What is "\*" supposed to be? For that matter, what is "+" supposed to be? I'm guessing that "-" is negation but I could be wrong.

Comment: No. Im trying to express a logic operater using arithmetic ones. I know thats weir

Comment: wierd. Its a homework. I also need to do this for logic or. So its plus minus and times

Comment: Ohhh ok. How could one know that.

Comment: Hint: What does $*$ do on $\{0,1\}$? What does $x \mapsto 1 - x$ do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since negation and conjunction form a functionally complete set of Boolean operators, it suffices to implement them. Take:
\begin{align*}
\textsf{Negation}(x) &= 1 - x \\
\textsf{Conjunction}(x, y) &= x \cdot y
\end{align*}